# Date constructor

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to initialize a `Date` object like this:

```
var d = new Date(24, 2, 1, 0, 0 ,0)
```

It seems to me, that the constructor is using `setYear` method instead of `setFullYear` so I end up with the year 1924, which would be completely fine in 99% cases, but now I need to be able to initialize date with any given year.

I've tried to use Date string like `Feb 2, 24 00:00:00` to get around this, but I end up with Feb 2, 2024. Next I've tried to find any workaround in [Date MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) but without any success.

I ended up using this beauty:

```
var d1 = new Date();
    d1.setFullYear(y);
    d1.setMonth(m);
    d1.setDate(d);
    d1.setHours(0);
    d1.setMinutes(0);
    d1.setSeconds(0);
```

which makes my eyes bleed, so I'm wondering, is there any solution / workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Ecma Script specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) states that year value in Date constructor is treated as follows

> If y is not NaN and 0 ≤ ToInteger(y) ≤ 99, then let yr be 1900+ToInteger(y); otherwise, let yr be y.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I tried this in Chrome and in Firefox with the same result:

```
new Date(24,2,12,0,0,0) //Wed Mar 12 1924 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
new Date(2024,2,12,0,0,0) //Tue Mar 12 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```

So it seems that this constructor uses setYear of setFullYear depending how big the value you pass is.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var d = new Date(y, m, d, 0, 0 ,0)
d.setFullYear(y);
```

Comment: I don't think he really wants 24 AD.

Comment: Hard to say from the question, may want 24, or 1924 or 2024, but he does state "but now I need to be able to initialize date with any given year." But this is a shorter way.